# What's the big deal about God's love by allowing Jesus to die and resurrect?

Tags: love

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is Christ's death so significant?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/how-is-christs-death-so-significant)

I actually expect lots of downvotes for this question as it's close to blasphemy and fear it will be closed. But with a purely positive aim in faith and humility, I need help with this question:

If many prophecies foretold Jesus' resurrection, what is the big deal about God's love in allowing Jesus to die for us?  After all, Jesus himself knew he would rise on the third day.

> "And he said unto them, These are the words which I spake unto you,
>   while I was yet with you, that all things must be fulfilled, which
>   were written in the law of Moses, and in the prophets, and in the
>   psalms, concerning me....And said unto them, Thus it is written, and
>   thus it behoved Christ to suffer, and to rise from the dead the third
>   day: " (Luke 24:46)

What special love have you shown if you lose something (even if it were the only one you had) out of sharing or sacrifice knowing definitely you will get the same thing back? 'Special' will fit if Jesus were dead forever like all men do.

I thought about this for a while and trust me, the only 'point' I could raise is the fact that Jesus had to go through physical pain, humiliation and torture which no man will be willing to go through for anyone. But I want more to justify that this sign of God's love, despite the resurrection, is more than the ordinary.

Comment: This is a great question, and even though you've phrased it differently, I think you'll find it's adequately answered in  [How is Christ's death so significant?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/how-is-christs-death-so-significant)

Comment: I was preparing to write an answer for this question drawing from some puritan writings, but Thomas is correct. This question is answered quite well by Caleb at the link Thomas posted. This in combination with the fact that the two questions are essentially the same, I think this one should be closed as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: +1 for what I think is a great question Christians really should know an answer to, but I really would give basically the same answer here add I gave to Marc. Even though I have a vested interest add it were, as the fourth voice in a row to think this is a duplicate, I'm casting my close vote too. If you have something not answered there, please edit this question to just focus on that unique bit and we can re-open it for you!