# According to evangelicalism, did Jesus' divine nature suffer on the cross?

Tags: christology, crucifixion, evangelicalism, suffering, hypostatic-union

From the evangelical perspective, considering that Jesus has both human and divine natures in one person, did His divine nature suffer on the cross along with his human nature?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For your question to work here, you would need to specify a Christian denomination whose answer you want. Otherwise it's far too broad for this site. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Comment: I don't think that you do need to specify only a single denomination, but it wouldn't hurt to clarify that you do want the Chalcedonian view of the Trinity (ie the view that Christ did have two natures, which is taught by Catholicism, Eastern, Orthodoxy and Protestant).

Comment: Interesting question as you ask if Christ's Divine nature suffered , yet did not die!

Comment: @KenGraham, astute observation as it wasn't explicitly stated in the question.  But of course we know from the Bible that God cannot die.  However, if death is defined as separation from God, was not Jesus experiencing this when He cried out, "My God, My God, why have You forsaken me?  (Up until that point in His suffering, Jesus had endured excruciating pain but had been silent, or in the case of the soldiers nailing Him to the cross, He prayed for their forgiveness!). His cry of forsakenness surely represented a separation of God the Son from God the Father as He endured the wrath of God.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as there are differences of belief about the nature of Christ, there are some different ideas about this in some branches of Christianity. However the mainline orthodox belief has a pretty settled answer to this: **yes**.

Assuming ⓐ the trinity, one God in three persons and ⓑ that Jesus was God the son having two complete natures, the logic goes something like this. Different branches of Christianity use different terms for some of this, but the basic argument is the same.

1. The ‘cup’ as referenced in Jesus' prayer was God's divine wrath against sin.
2. Yes Jesus bore physical suffering as a human and his human nature bore the brunt of the pain the Romans inflicted.
3. But the significance of the cross was more than just a Roman torture and execution, he was also subjected to God's wrath.
4. “Why have you forsaken me?” was not a question about why he was left to hang on at tree, it was an expression of God turning his back on his son, subjecting him to ‘death’ in the sense of separation from God.
5. No human nature would have been able to bear *that* punishment inflicted directly by God — ­he would have neither the stamina nor the value to make such an action more meaningful than it was for the thieves he was crucified with.

Ergo the divine nature of God must have been subjected to and born the divine wrath side of things.

I question some time ago that asks about the same problem from a different angle, see [How is Christ's death so significant?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/2329/30) for a little more detail on the significance of “one man on a cross”.

Comment: The Bible says 'God made Him to be sin Who knew no sin, that we might  be made the righteousness of God in Him.'  It would seem Jesus as a divine member of the Trinity could not be made sin since He is perfectly holy.  Perhaps in His human nature He was made utterly sinful , and in His nature as God, He suffered  both the weight of that sin vicariously and the 'lostness' of being separated from God.  Was that separation itself, then, the wrath of God?  (The concept of 'hypo-static union' I've heard before seems somewhat elusive in that it doesn't convey information about the relationship.)

Comment: @Robwest This is quickly headed down a road towards being a “truth question”, a sort we [don't handle on this site](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3527/30). I answered it as an overview of what the most prevalent belief is on this issue. If you want to argue that's not correct then this whole thing will end up being off topic for this site. You may want to do some more research (there are many good books covering this topic) or ask specific questions about how various theological traditions deal with this issue, but comments aren't for starting a discussion about your own theory.

Comment: This is really not an overview, but a generalized *Protestant* answer to the question. Only Protestantism subscribes to [penal substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penal_substitution), which is the basis of this answer. The question *is* a truth question, and should be closed unless it is either scoped to a particular denomination or explicitly made into an overview question. And even if it were made into an overview question, this answer does not provide an overview of the major Christian viewpoints on this question, since it doesn't even cover Catholicism and Orthodox Christianity.

Comment: @Lee This line of reasoning is not specific to Protestantism nor does it depend on penal substitution. Catholicism and Orthodoxy have different expressions of “atonement” that vary substantially, but this basic line of reasoning that it was important during his death that he was more than just a man and that he could bear more or was worth more because of being God is still there in some form. I didn't claim this represents 100% of so called Christian views, but covering Protestantism, Catholicism and Orthodoxy is the lion's share.

Comment: This is *definitely* not a line of reasoning that [Eastern Christianity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atonement_in_Christianity#Eastern_Christianity) accepts about the nature of the atonement. And "to bear *that* punishment in the place of all of humanity" is a specifically Protestant, penal-substitution-based line of reasoning, which is not accepted in Catholicism even if some of the rest of the reasoning is. This is very clearly a *Protestant* line of reasoning, and not an overview.

Comment: The link is to the section on Eastern Christianity in the "Atonement in Christianity" article on Wikipedia. It shows that Eastern Christianity does not accept the wrath-based, satisfaction or substitutionary theories of atonement that are the basis of Catholic and Protestant soteriology, the Protestant version of which you have outlined.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden Did you miss the bit where I started off with _«Different branches of Christianity use different terms for some of this»_? Sure my terminology is very Protestant flavored, but the basic logic of some or all of those points being brought together does hold for all three main traditions.

Comment: This article argues that ideas of penal substitution may be found throughout Church history, and are not a peculiarly Protestant innovation: https://www.tms.edu/m/tmsj20i.pdf  It cites for its support: Ignatius, the Epistle of Barnabas, the Epistle to
Diognetus, Justin Martyr, Eusebius of Caesarea, Eusebius of Emesa, Hilary of Poitiers, Athanasius, Basil the Great, Gregory of Nazianzus, Ambrose of Milan, John Chrysostom, Augustine of Hippo, Cyril of Alexandria, Severus of Antioch, Oecumenius, and Martin Luther.

Comment: @Caleb I'm sorry, but that is simply not true. It is *not* just a matter of terminology. And it is a common (and very annoying) error of Protestants to think that all Christians agree with their doctrines. Did you actually read the linked article section on Eastern Christianity's view of atonement? It says: "Thus the Orthodox emphasis would be that Christ died, *not to appease an angry and vindictive Father or to avert the wrath of God upon sinners,* but to defeat and secure the destruction of sin and death" (emphasis added). Your answer does not *at all* describe Eastern views of atonement.

Comment: @Caleb Catholicism, also, does not accept the penal substitution model that you have outlined. Their doctrine of atonement has come to be based primarily on Anselm's [satisfaction theory of atonement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfaction_theory_of_atonement), which does *not* involve Jesus taking the penalty for our sins, but rather Jesus satisfying the honor of the Father. Although penal substitution developed out of Anselmian satisfaction theory, it is a *different* theory, and it is not believed outside of Protestantism.

Comment: @Caleb You are, of course, free to believe what you want about the Atonement and salvation. But you are in complete error if you think that the other branches of Christianity agree with Protestantism on these matters. They do not, as you can see simply by reading the various Wikipedia articles on these subjects. Therefore once again, your answer is *not* an overview, even if the question had *asked* for an overview, which it didn't.

Comment: @PaulChernoch I've read that article before. But the author is reading penal substitution *into* all of those quotes. Those early authors were not talking about penal substitution, but about ransom theory and Christus Victor, which were the primary theories of atonement in the first thousand years of Christianity. This is a perfect example of Protestants thinking everyone else believes what they do about atonement and salvation. Catholic and Orthodox scholars do not accept Vlatch's and other Protestants' interpretations of those early church fathers.

Comment: @PaulChernoch All you have to do is read the very first sentence of the [penal substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penal_substitution) article on Wikipedia to see that: "Penal substitution . . . is a theory of the atonement within Christian theology, *developed with the Reformed tradition*" (emphasis added). And the very first sentence of the "History" section reads: "In scholarly literature it has been generally recognised for some time that the penal substitution theory was not taught in the Early Church." Beyond that, the history of penal substitution isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: @Caleb Jesus frequently cited the OT when he taught.  His disciples called him Rabbi.  Teaching was his thing.  Citing the opening line of Psalm 22 was Him teaching the audience who was mocking him: the Pharisees/Priests who asked him why he did not save himself.  He was speaking in shorthand for those who knew the OT; "I know how this ends, and I knew this was coming."  It's the same as me saying "the Lord is my shephard" and everyone in my men's group knowing exactly what I am referring to (Psalm 23 and its message).